# How to select an option in MUI select list with jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI select component id like to automate tests with jest. Is it possible to select an option within a list selector Material UI component and have the option populate its value confirmably in jest? I am unable to find any reliable method or information on how to do this.

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930419/how-to-simulate-selecting-from-dropdown-in-jest-enzyme-testing, please verify the given solution. This should work if not let me know.

Comment: @polar please add the snippet about what you have tried so far so that we can help you.
Also add relevant details to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React testing library on change for Material UI Select component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184037/react-testing-library-on-change-for-material-ui-select-component)

Answer (score 0):

In MUI library all input components have a property called `inputProps`.
This property is forwarded to the html `<input />` at the end of the tree. So you can pass a property that identifies the input so you can use it to find and interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

MUI isn't that different.

Have you tried something like this?

```
import {render, screen, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react'

test('should pick select option', () => {
  render(<MyCustomMUIComponent />)
  const select = screen.getByLabelText('My Select');
  fireEvent.click(select);
  const option = screen.getByText('First Option');
  fireEvent.click(option);

  // the effect you want to test for
})
```

Comment: Didn't work for me when using `<Select data-testid="mytestid" defaultValue='option_1'>
    <MenuItem value='option_1'>option_1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value='option_2'>option_2</MenuItem>
    </Select>` (and replacing `getByLabelText` with `getByTestId`)

Answer (score 0):

This way of doing things worked for me:

```
test('MUI Select test', async () => {
  const spyOnSelectChange = jest.fn();

  render(<Select defaultValue='option_1_key'
          onChange={spyOnSelectChange}>
            <MenuItem value='option_1_key'>option_1_value</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='option_2_key'>option_2_value</MenuItem>
        </Select>)

  // Check current state
  {
    expect(screen.queryByText('option_1_value')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(screen.queryByText('option_2_value')).not.toBeTruthy();
  }

  // Change Selection
  {
    // Note: you need to use the *keys*, not the actual text shown
    const select = screen.getByDisplayValue("option_1_key")
    // no act/await needed (why?)
    fireEvent.change(select, { target: { value: 'option_2_key' } })
  }
  

  // check if onChange was called
  expect(spyOnSelectChange.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);

  // Check new state
  {
    expect(screen.queryByText('option_1_value')).not.toBeTruthy();
    expect(screen.queryByText('option_2_value')).toBeTruthy();
  }
})
```

#### Note:

- `const select = screen.getByTestId("your_test_id");` wouldn't work.
- [Another answer stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68216785/6702598) you'd need `await waitFor(() => {expect(spyOnSelectChange.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);})`. I didn't.